# Is there a method to return pushed element to array from .filter/.map in single array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter, fetch-api

I have to done chart.js but i can't because in JSON value i need to have array of numbers.
The problem is to map object with two keys day, amount. I need only amount and i need arrays of amuont. My question for this post is :

- method for make numeric array like [0,1,2..] from fetch method where get data by data.json local file and make a map/filter then make array with only amount key but the array need to be made only by values of JSON.

my javascript script :

```
<script>
  fetch('data.json')
  .then(result => result.json())
  .then(response => response.map((response) => { var data = response }));

  const labels = [
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thusday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday',
    'Sunday'
  ];
  const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First Dataset',
      data: !!!!!!THERE_GO_AMOUNT_ARRAY LIKE => [10,20,30,40,50] !!!!! from (response) => { var data = response })
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
        'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
        'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
        'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  };
  
  const config = {
      type: 'bar',
      data: data,
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      },
    };
    const mychart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config
    );
  </script>
```

My data :

```
[
  {
    "day": "mon",
    "amount": 17.45
  },
  {
    "day": "tue",
    "amount": 34.91
  },
  {
    "day": "wed",
    "amount": 52.36
  },
  {
    "day": "thu",
    "amount": 31.07
  },
  {
    "day": "fri",
    "amount": 23.39
  },
  {
    "day": "sat",
    "amount": 43.28
  },
  {
    "day": "sun",
    "amount": 25.48
  }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: no, this answer doesn't respond to my question because there is not data manipulation on frontend, in this project i haven't backend, i just send fetch() request to get data.json from my local project file i have : index.html data.json and style.css and i want use fetch() method, i'm new to programming..

Comment: It should since you're doing `var data = response` in the then callback. Which won't do what you want

Comment: it's good observation, i have undefined value with that code